# How to stop update progress bar for every timer click event

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have asp page with update progress control. I want to rebind grid view every 5 sec. so i am using timer control. but my problem is update progress bar showing every  timer click event. how to resolve this.Please help me.

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" DisplayAfter="0" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel">
      <ProgressTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" CssClass="overlay" runat="server">
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" CssClass="loader" runat="server">
               <img src="../../images/bx_loader.gif" alt="" />                             
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server"  UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger EventName="SelectedIndexChanged ControlID="gvMessages" />
          </Triggers>
           <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Timer ID="timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" ></asp:Timer>

                   <asp:GridView ID="gvMessages" Width="100%"  CssClass="mail-block" runat="server">
                   </asp:GridView>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtWorkFlow" runat="server" > </asp:TextBox>


     </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
 </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Perhaps it would help identify the problem if you could share your code?